# Stop API execution flow on empty result set

Tags: metamug

I want the execution of my request to stop if one of my query tags returns an empty result set.

```
<Query> Select * from sample_table </Query>
```

Comment: Do you have more queries after this one in the request tag? Assuming this is a GET request

Answer (score 2):

Use onblank attribute of a query tag, but you need to use persist as well. Or what you could do is persist the result set and check it in the next query or update tag using when="$resultSet ne null".. I would recommend you to use the onblank with persist.

```xml
<Query persist="true" onblank="The execution stopped because a query 
returned an empty result set.">
    Select * from sample_table 
</Query>
```

Comment: From where you got `$resultSet`?